# HTML Submit button to send text areas to email

Tags: html, forms, email, text, submit

So, for example comment section in web page -> you type comment -> click "Submit" button -> comment will be sent to specified email.

Lets say my email is kaster@gmail.com
I want that when you click submit button it will send text area above to my email.

I would be grateful if someone made whole HTML code for comment section with submit button which will be sent to my email. Also would be nice to have multiple text areas to be sent, for example "Name" and "Comment".

Another thing if you are interested to discuss, same thing but Submit button saves text area to text file which I can check later. It might be tricky as it needs to edit text file when someone adds new comment without admin rights to server. But just asking.
Mainly would like to know that Submit area(s) sending to email.

Comment: You need a server side program to submit to. You can't go directly from form to email (not in a usefully supported way, at least). So start by picking a programming language that your server supports.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Quentin stated, you need a language like PHP to process the user inputs and create an email out of it. There's no pure HTML way to do it.

google took me to http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php which seems to be doing roughly what you want.